# Listing all Items under a Category C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like some direction on how to be able to list all the items under a certain category in a view. I have already searched around and can't find anything, If someone know of any other posts or articles please point me there. Other wise here is my model...

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItem { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: You can loop over the items in the view. You need to set the model for the view to the Model you wanna loop over.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your category is set at the model

```
@foreach(var item in Model.MenuItem)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ID)
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</div>
    // carry on with other properties / markup
}
```

Comment: I've done that and I can display all my MenuItems, but i am looking for a way to display MenuItems under a certain category.

Comment: That sounds a little more involved - perhaps you would like to edit the question to clarify exactly what you mean

Comment: People on here are the most helpful a holes ever... hahaha. Got my post deleted for saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to loop over the `MenuItem` property in the `Category` model, in your view you'd have something like this:

At the top of the View, you'd have this:
`@model Category`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MenuItem)
   {
      <tr id="menu-item">
        <td>@id</td>
        <td>@Name</td>
        <td>@Description</td>
        <td>@Image</td>
      </tr>
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MenuItem)
{
<tr>
    <td>@Name</td>
    <td>@Description</td>     
</tr>
{
```